# What is the angularJs way to pass variable value back to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angularJs. I am having a page which uses the ng-repeat to generate new records:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in objs">
  <td>
    <input type="text" value="{{obj.name}}" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" value="{{obj.amount}}" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" value="{{obj.status}}" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

As they are all input fields. All of the data are writable to the customer. When submitting form, I am trying to get the updated data. Using the code below:

```
$scope.submitform = function(index) {
  var objJson = JSON.stringify($scope.objs);
  $('input[id$="objList"]').val(objJson);
  saveForm();
}
```

But seems $scope.objs is not updated by customer input, which I can quite understand. But the problem is, how should I pass the values back to $scope.objs? I can definitely use the jQuery to do that but which might not sound very angularJs. So what is the best way in angularJs to achieve that?

Comment: Why are you not using `ngModel`?

Comment: @Satpal because I haven't learnt that yet... I am reading the document about it now

Comment: use <input type="text" ng-model="inputTest" value="{{obj.name}}"/> and you can access it in controller using scope like $scope.inputTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ng-model` instead of `value`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in objs">
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="obj.name"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="obj.amount"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="obj.status"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This will update `$scope.objs` when the user edits an `input` field.

It works because `ng-model` is binding the value of the `input` with the field specified in the `ng-model` attribute, and `obj` is just an alias for `objs[$index]` (`$index` is supplied automatically by angular inside `ng-repeat`).

So in this `input` field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.name"/>
```

you are binding `input.value` with `$scope.objs[$index].name`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-model` for passing value to controller.

Demo for ng-model

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.firstName = "Krupesh";
  $scope.lastName = "Kotecha";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
  <br>
  Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both answers work for me quite well. I clicked add one for this answer. But since Ron's answer is more concise which directly points to my issue, I chose his as selected.

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a **MVVM** architecture. You can bind any controller data to the view(i.e html) and access changed data in controller.

If you want to send only data from controller to HTML you can use **ngBind** directive. If you want to two way binding i.e. from controller to HTML and from HTML to controller also then use **ngModel** directive. In current scenario you require ngModel directive.

Please see below code :

```
                 <tr ng-repeat="obj in objs">
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="obj.name" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="obj.amount" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="obj.status" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

When you change any data from HTML , It automatically reflect in your angular's controller. i.e in $scope.objs object.